# Does using & in the parameters of a C++ program change how it runs?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

13. Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int f(int x, int& y)
{
    x = x + y;
    y = x + 2;
    return (x + 5);
}
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 5;
    int c = 30;
    c = f(a, b);
    cout << a + b + c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Which number is output by this program? Select exactly one.

A) 12

B) 15

C) 17

D) 19

E) 20

F) 24

G) 25

H) 27

I) 36

J) 37

K) 38

L) 39

M) 41

N) 43

O) 51

I got 17, but the answer is listed as 20.

17 made sense to me as x=x+y would assign 6 to x, then the function would return (x+5), or 11, this is then added to 1 and 5 in the main function to print 17.

But the answer is listed as 20. Any help please thanks.

I thought 17 would be output, but 20 was actually output.

Comment: Do you what `&` is in C++?

Comment: Yes. `int x` means `x` is a copy of the argument used in the call. In this case `x` contains the same value `main`'s `a` had when the call was made.  Because it is a copy, it is a different object and you can change the value of `x` without changing the value of `a`. `int & y` means `y` is a reference to the argument used in the call. `y` is another name for `main`'s `b`. Since `y` and `b` are the same object, you can change the value of `b` by changing `y`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Because of the `&`, `y` correspond to `b` modified. And the result is `1+8+11=20`.

Answer (score 3):

The function `f()` takes two integers, `x` by value, and `y` [**by reference**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference). This means that in the function, `x` is a new copy of whatever gets passed in, and `y` is another name for the original variable. Which is `b` in this case.

So in your `main()`, the line `c = f(a, b);` is `c = f(1, 5);`.

In `f()`, `x` is a copy, meaning that `a` will remain unaffected. We know your sum is `1 + b + c`.

Back to `f()`. `x` is immediately reassigned to `1 + 5`, so the copy `x` has a value of 6.

`y` gets reassigned, to `6 + 2`, 8. But remember that `y` was passed as a reference to `b`, so the value of `b` is also now 8. So the sum is `1 + 8 + c`.

Now we consider the return statement in `f()` which assigns to `c`. `x` is 6, and `6 + 5` is 11. So back in `main()`, the line `c = f(a, b);` assigns 11 to `c`.

The sum is `1 + 8 + 11`, which evaluates to 20.

Answer (score 0):

In the function, "f", the argument "int x" means a copy is made for whatever is passed as the first argument. This means that whatever changes you make to "x" during the function call will not last once the function returns because they are being done to a copy of x and not the original. However, the second argument is passed by reference, hence "int& y". This means that changes made to the second argument will last once the function returns. So now let's step through the code.

`x = x + y` means "x" = 6 (i.e. 1 + 5). On the next line, we see
`y = x + 2` where "y" = 6 + 2, which means that b is now set to 8.
Finally, we have that `c = 6 + 5`, which means
`a + b + c = 1 + 8 + 11 = 20.`